# Voltage sources in parallel Kirchhoff volage law

Tags: voltage, kirchhoffs-laws

Can somebody please tell me how can I apply Kirchhoff voltage law in the following circuit??
Is there a way to find an equivalent circuit for the sources V1,V2 and resistors R1 and R2??

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpd021.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't yet covered the general case where R1 and R2 are different. You can use nodal analysis or a Thevenin equivalent, but you can also take a more mathematical approach and use plain KVL. Each path around the circuit gives a different equation. Let's say \$R_1 = 200\ \Omega\$ and \$R_2 = 500\ \Omega\$. We'll define \$I_1\$ as the current through \$R_1\$ and \$I_2\$ as the current through \$R_2\$. There are two possible paths:

$$5\ \mathrm V - 4700\ \Omega \cdot (I_1 + I_2) - 0.6\ \mathrm V - 200\ \Omega \cdot I_1 = 0$$

$$5\ \mathrm V - 4700\ \Omega \cdot (I_1 + I_2) - 0.6\ \mathrm V - 500\ \Omega \cdot I_2 = 0$$

That's two equations in two unknowns, which means we can find a solution. We can solve for the currents by hand or using a convenient tool such as [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20systems%20of%20equations&a=*C.solve%20systems%20of%20equations-_*Calculator.dflt-&a=FSelect_**SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator-.dflt-&f3=5%20-%204700*%28x%20%2B%20y%29%20-%200.6%20-%20200*x%20%3D%200&f=SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator.equation1_5%20-%204700*%28x%20%2B%20y%29%20-%200.6%20-%20200*x%20%3D%200&f4=5%20-%204700*%28x%20%2B%20y%29%20-%200.6%20-%20y*500%20%3D%200&f=SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator.equation2%5Cu005f5%20-%204700*%28x%20%2B%20y%29%20-%200.6%20-%20y*500%20%3D%200). The solutions are:

$$I_1 \approx 650\ \mathrm{\mu A}$$
$$I_2 \approx 260\ \mathrm{\mu A}$$

Now consider the case where the two resistors are equal \$(R_1 = R_2 = 270\ \Omega)\$.

$$5\ \mathrm V - 4700\ \Omega \cdot (I_1 + I_2) - 0.6\ \mathrm V - 270\ \Omega \cdot I_1 = 0$$
$$5\ \mathrm V - 4700\ \Omega \cdot (I_1 + I_2) - 0.6\ \mathrm V - 270\ \Omega \cdot I_2 = 0$$

We can solve these as simultaneous equations just like before. But notice how similar the equations are! Nothing changes except the name of the variable. But the name of the variable is meaningless -- we can number the currents however we want. Since we can swap the two equations (and thus the two branches) without being able to tell the difference, \$I_1\$ must equal \$I_2\$. We say that the two branches are *symmetrical*. Symmetry is a powerful concept in mathematics and the sciences. It allows us to simplify our analysis by eliminating variables. If you've studied Gauss's Law in physics, you've already seen symmetry in action.

All this is a fancy mathematical way of saying that when you have two identical branches in parallel, their currents must be the same. That lets us write a single equation:

$$5\ \mathrm V - 4700\ \Omega \cdot (I_{12} + I_{12}) - 0.6\ \mathrm V - 270\ \Omega \cdot I_{12} = 0$$

$$4.4\ \mathrm V - (2 \cdot 4700\ \Omega + 270\ \Omega)I_{12} = 0$$

$$I_{12} \approx 455\ \mathrm{\mu A}$$

where \$I_{12}\$ is the current through either one of the branches.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to find an equivalent circuit for the sources V1,V2 and
>   resistors R1 and R2??

If the outputs are connected and V1 = V2 then the sources can be connected. This means R1 and R2 are effectively in parallel.

This means it becomes a voltage source of V1 in series with R1 || R2 or, in the example given the series resistance is 135 ohms.

Comment: Can I ask what happens in case V1 is not equal to V2?

Comment: Without a load, a current flows between the voltage sources i.e. a circulating current flows around V1, R1, V2 and R2. The voltage after V1 and V2 is the average of both if R1 and R2 are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Kirchof's voltage low is an equation. You just have to writ it down:

V3 + V12 - V1 = 0
V3 + V12 - V2 = 0

Then write down the Kirchof's current law for the node in the center:

I3 - I1 - I2 = 0

Substitute the voltages:

(V3-V12)/R3 - (V12 - V1) / R1 - (V12 - V2) / R3 = 0

I think that's it, just solve it now. And in case i made mistakes there- write down the equations by yourself.

Comment: V12 is equal to what??

Comment: The voltage on the common plus of v1 and v2. find out from equations, i am too lazy

Comment: By the way, check youself by replacing those two branches with 600mv and 135R resistor.

Comment: This is what I meant when I said to find an equivalent for the sources in parallel. In this case I will have just one current right???

Comment: Yes, but it has nothing to do with kirchoff's law. It's just the symmetry.

Comment: yeah , maybe I did not phrase it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Just by inspection, V1R1 is in parallel with V2R2 so, since equal voltages in parallel don't change and a pair of equal resistances in parallel yield a total resistance of half of either, we have:

[image]

Next, since V1 and V2 are fighting each other, the total voltage available to push current through the circuit is going to be:

$$ Vt = V1 - V2 = 5V - 0.6V = 4.4 \text{ volts,}$$

and the total current through the circuit will then be:

$$ It = \frac{Vt}{R1+R2} = \frac{4.4V}{4835\Omega} = 910 \text{ microamperes} $$

Finally, the voltage dropped across R2 will be:

$$ V(R2) = It \times R2 $$

and the voltage dropped across R1 will be:

$$ V(R1) = It \times R1 $$